# Mutation not updating Graphcache cache entry in urql

Tags: graphql, urql

I am working on a skin care website, and it lets you create skin care routines (`Routine` in type-defs) with information about how you use your skin care products (`ProductUsage`s in type-defs).

Routine and ProductUsages are many-to-many relations. In type-defs,

```
  type Routine {
    id: ID!
    # ...
    productUsages: [ProductUsage!]
  }

  type ProductUsage {
    id: ID!
    # ...
    routines: [Routine]
  }
```

On the routine page, urql runs the `currentRoutine` query like this:

```
const ROUTINE_QUERY = gql`
  query CurrentRoutineQuery($routineId: ID!, $ownerId: ID!) {
    currentRoutine(ownerId: $ownerId) {
      productUsages {
        id
        productId
        name
        brand
        category {
          id
          label
        }
        frequency
        rating
      }
      id
    }
    productsWithOtherUsers(routineId: $routineId)
  }
`;
```

(only `currentRoutine` query is relevant but including everything here just in case)
As you can see, even though it queries a `Routine`, I'm more interested in `ProductUsage`s in that routine.

Its type-def is as follows:

```
    currentRoutine(ownerId: ID!): Routine
```

On the same page, users can search and submit new `ProductUsage`s, with the following type-defs.

```
    createProductUsageInfo(input: CreateProductUsageInfoInput): ProductUsage
```

I run this mutation like

```
const CREATE_PRODUCT_INFO_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation createProductUsageInfo($input: CreateProductUsageInfoInput) {
    createProductUsageInfo(input: $input) {
      id
      weeklyFrequency
      dailyFrequency
      rating
      comment
      routines {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

In the resolver, I create and return a `productUsage`, and include the related `routines` entity. Graphcache uses `id` as the key, so I made sure to query `id` for the `productUsage`, and for the included `routines`.

However, the `productUsages` in `currentRoutine` query cache, which I mentioned in the beginning, doesn't reflect the new `ProductUsage` entry created from this mutation. On the urql cache explorer, `productUsages` doesn't change.
[image]

What could I be doing wrong? I've spent so much time over the last few weeks trying to debug this.
The only thing that I can think of is that the `productUsages` in currentRoutines result returned from the resolver looks like `productUsages: [{productUsage: {id: 1, ...}}, {productUsage: {id: 2, ...}}]`, so I included the following resolver under `Routine` to transform it like `productUsages: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ...}]`.

```
    async productUsages(parent) {
      return parent.productUsages.map(
        (productUsage) => productUsage.productUsage
      );
    }
```

Maybe it doesn't recognize the `id` because of this? I'm really not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided your logic for updating the Graphcache, so it looks like you assumed that it will be updated passively (automatically).

But as the [urql's documentation on cache updates](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/cache-updates/) says, you need to create an updater when creating new entities (see "Updating lists or links").

Since your query has variables, the Graphcache may store multiple `CurrentRoutineQuery` — we can update all of them.

In TypeScript, you can generate an equivalent of your `CREATE_PRODUCT_INFO_MUTATION` using the GraphQL Code Generator (`@graphql-codegen/cli`) ([a guide for React and Vue](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/react-vue)). It will be called `CreateProductInfoDocument`. But you can write it manually as well.

Navigate to your `createClient` and in your `cacheExchange`, try writing something like this.
Note: the `as` assertions are coming from TypeScript and refer to the types generated by `@graphql-codegen/cli` — you can ignore them.

```typescript
cacheExchange({
  updates: {
    Mutation: {
      createProductUsageInfo: (result, args, cache, info) => {
        // Update all currentRoutine queries
        const newProductUsageInfo = (result as CreateProductUsageInfoMutation)
          .createProductUsageInfo;
        if (newProductUsageInfo) {
          cache
            .inspectFields("Query")
            .filter((field) => field.fieldName === "currentRoutine")
            .forEach((field) => {
              cache.updateQuery(
                {
                  query: CurrentRoutineDocument,
                  variables: field.arguments as QueryCurrentRoutineArgs,
                },
                (data) => {
                  if (newProductUsageInfo) {
                    (
                      data as CurrentRoutineQuery
                    ).currentRoutine.productUsages.unshift(newProductUsageInfo);
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              );
            });
        }
      },
```

`unshift()` will put the new `ProductUsageInfo` at the beginning of the displayed array.

If you get stuck, try following [this example](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/cache-updates/#updating-many-unknown-links) from urql's docs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `__typename` in the response. This is needed for URQL to match the ID to a key (`Product:123`). In addition to `id`, be sure to specify `__typename`. If you're using graphql-codegen, it has an option to do this automatically.

Your updated query would be:

```js
const ROUTINE_QUERY = gql`
  query CurrentRoutineQuery($routineId: ID!, $ownerId: ID!) {
    currentRoutine(ownerId: $ownerId) {
      productUsages {
        id
        productId
        name
        brand
        category {
          id
          label
          __typename
        }
        frequency
        rating
        __typename
      }
      id
      __typename
    }
    __typename
    productsWithOtherUsers(routineId: $routineId)
  }
`;
```

Then, do the same for your mutation:

```js
const CREATE_PRODUCT_INFO_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation createProductUsageInfo($input: CreateProductUsageInfoInput) {
    createProductUsageInfo(input: $input) {
      id
      weeklyFrequency
      dailyFrequency
      rating
      comment
      __typename
      routines {
        id
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Remember, only the fields you fetch in your mutation will update the cache. So in this case, your `routines` isn't updating any fields, since you're just fetching a list of them. But if that's intended, then that's fine.